# Actionbar in listactivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to show some menus in my action bar and need to have action bar in my application activity but I'm using Listactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyList.getInstance().getReminders();
    list();
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), locser.class));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menu1 = menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Start Service");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == 1) {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), locser.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
void list()
{
    setListAdapter(new listadapter(this, R.layout.reminder_list_layout, MyList.getInstance().getReminders()));
    reminders rem1=new reminders();
    rem1.address="hello";
    rem1.name="je";
    MyList.getInstance().getReminders().add(rem1);
}
```

How to add action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your Android minimum API-14 or later, add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

under your ListView_Activity in AndroidManifest.xml class put this:

```
 <activity android:name=".Your_ListView_Activity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
              android:label="ListView_Activity_Label">
```